# List names and number of occurrences

Tags: java, arrays

So the task was to read a file with the following names:

```
Alice
Bob 
James  
Richard  
Bob  
Alice  
Alice  
Alice  
James  
Richard  
Bob 
Richard  
Bob  
Stephan  
Michael  
Henry
```

And print out each name with its value of occurrence e.g "Alice - <4>".

 I got it working, basically. The only problem I have is that the last name (Stephan - <1>) is missing in my output and I can't get it to work properly.. It's probably because I used [i-1] but as I said, I'm not getting the right solution here. 
Well, here's my code..

```
package Assignment4;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ReportUniqueNames {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.println ("       This programm counts words, characters and lines!\n");
        System.out.println ("Please enter the name of the .txt file:");

        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (System.in));

        BufferedReader read = null;
        String file = "";
        String text = "";
        String line = "";
        boolean unique = true;
        int nameCounter = 1;        

        try {

            file = input.readLine();
            read = new BufferedReader (new FileReader(file));
            while ((line = read.readLine()) != null) {
                text += line.trim() + " ";                  
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File was not found.");          
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("An error has occured.");            
        }

        String textarray[] = text.split(" ");
        Arrays.sort(textarray);

        for (int i=0; i < textarray.length; i++) {

            if (i > 0 && textarray[i].equals(textarray[i-1])) {
                nameCounter++;
                unique = false;
            }

            if (i > 0 && !textarray[i].equals(textarray[i-1]) && !unique) {
                    System.out.println("<"+textarray[i-1]+"> - <"+nameCounter+">");
                    nameCounter = 1;
                    unique = true;
            } else if (i > 0 && !textarray[i].equals(textarray[i-1]) && unique) {
                //nameCounter = 1;
                System.out.println("<"+textarray[i-1]+"> - <"+nameCounter+">");
            }           

        }

    }

}
```

So that's it.. Hopefully one of you could help me out.

**EDIT:**
 Wow, so many different approaches. 
 First of all thanks for all of your help. 
I'll look through your suggested solutions and maybe restart from the bottom ;).
 Will give you a heads up when I'm done.

Comment: You have over-complicated code, which is difficult to debug. Try using [`Files.readAllLines`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset)) and [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) for counting.

Comment: `Stephan` is actually not the last name in the input file given -- providing proper input and expected output will make answering the question much easier..

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg, I agree, I thought about the `readAllLines` approach but I opted to read all the contents into a `String` and then converted them into a `List<String` using the `asList()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use a `Map` (that emulates a "[Multiset](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multiset)") for the purpose of counting words:

```
String textarray[] = text.split(" ");

// TreeMap gives sorting by alphabetical order "for free"
Map<String, Integer> wordCounts = new TreeMap<>();

for (int i = 0; i < textarray.length; i++) {
    Integer count = wordCounts.get(textarray[i]);
    wordCounts.put(textarray[i], count != null ? count + 1 : 1);
}

for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> e : wordCounts.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("<" + e.getKey() + "> - <" + e.getValue() + ">");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)** to read your input file (whose location is denoted by `"filepath"`) using **the new line character as your delimiter** and add the words directly to an `ArrayList<String>`.

Then, iterate the `ArrayList<String>` and count the frequency of each word in your original file in a `HashMap<String, Integer>`.

**Full Working Code:**

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("filepath")).useDelimiter("\n");
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
while (s.hasNext()){
    list.add(s.next());
}
s.close();

Map<String, Integer> wordFrequency = new HashMap<>();

for(String str : list)
{
    if(wordFrequency.containsKey(str))
        wordFrequency.put(str, wordFrequency.get(str) + 1); // Increment the frequency by 1
    else
        wordFrequency.put(str, 1);
}

//Print the frequency:
for(String str : list)
{
    System.out.println(str + ": " + wordFrequency.get(str));
}
```

**EDIT:**

Alternatively, you can read the **entire file into a single `String`** and then split the contents of the `String` using `\n` as delimiter into a list. The code is shorter than the first option:

```
String fileContents = new Scanner(new File("filepath")).useDelimiter("\\Z").next(); // \Z is the end of string anchor, so the entire file is read in one call to next()
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(fileContents.split("\\s*\\n\\s*"));// Using new line character as delimiter, it adds every word to the list
```

Comment: Reading the entire file into a single String is a very interesting solution.

Comment: @Aprendiz - Besides providing some syntactic sugar, it might actually be more efficient in terms of I/O to read it all into a single `String`. I'm not entirely sure though and hopefully someone else can shed more light on this.

Comment: If no one else comments on this it would be a very good question to ask.. :)

Comment: @BruceWayne the best we can do in this situation is process the lines while reading them, so you won't store all the file in RAM, but only the processed line. Storing of the whole big file (for example, 1G) will be very expensive.

Comment: @Dmitry good point. But from a time complexity point of view, is it the most efficient solution?

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg, Could you elaborate on your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30552098/what-are-the-advantages-and-diadvantages-of-reading-an-entire-file-into-a-single)

Comment: @Aprendiz, thanks for the tip, I posted a new question. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30552098/what-are-the-advantages-and-diadvantages-of-reading-an-entire-file-into-a-single)'s the link.

Comment: @BruceWayne I don't have any answers on this question, only comment :)

Comment: @Aprendiz the **complexity** (theoretical) wouldn't change, although for little file, it might be faster to read the whole file, for the big file this approach will fail, because even if your file fits in the RAM, it doesn't fit into the faster parts of it.

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg _"even if your file fits in the RAM, it doesn't fit into the faster parts of it."_ - What does this mean? I didn't understand, sorry :/

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this:

```
Map<String,Integer> occurs = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
int i = 0, number;

for (; i < textarray.length; i++) {
   if (occurs.containsKey(textarray[i])) {
      number = occurs.get(testarray[i]);
      occurs.put(testarray[i], number + 1);
   } else {
      occurs.put(testarray[i], 1);
   }
}

for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : occurs.entrySet()){
     System.out.println("<" + entry.getKey() + "> - " + entry.getValue()); 
}
```

Comment: `occurs.put(testarray[i], number);` -> `occurs.put(testarray[i], number + 1);`. Also, the code for iteration will be quite useful (`occurs.entrySet()`?)

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("<"+textarray[textarray.length-1]+"> - <"+nameCounter+">");
```

you need this after your loop because you print only till i-1 even though your loop runs correct number of times

But using a map is a better choice

Answer (score 0):

Because your code prints the results for a name the first time that that name isn't the same any more. Then you are missing a print statement for the last entry. To solve this you can just add another if statement at the end of your loop that checks if this is the last time the loop will loop. The if statement would look like this:

```
if(i == textarray.length - 1){
    System.out.println("<"+textarray[i]+"> - <"+nameCounter+">");
}
```

Now the loop will look like this:

```
for (int i=1; i < textarray.length; i++) {

        if (i > 0 && textarray[i].equals(textarray[i-1])) {
            nameCounter++;
            unique = false;
        }
            if (i > 0 && !textarray[i].equals(textarray[i-1]) && !unique) {
                System.out.println("<"+textarray[i-1]+"> - <"+nameCounter+">");
                nameCounter = 1;
                unique = true;
            }

            else if (i > 0 && !textarray[i].equals(textarray[i-1]) && unique) {
                //nameCounter = 1;
                System.out.println("<"+textarray[i-1]+"> - <"+nameCounter+">");
            }
            if(i == textarray.length - 1){
                System.out.println("<"+textarray[i]+"> - <"+nameCounter+">");
            }
    }
```

And now the loop will also print the results for the last entry in the list.

I hope this helps :)

P.S. some of the other solutions here are far more efficient but this is a solution for your current approach.

Comment: thanks a lot! I tried something similar to this, but it just did not work.

Comment: No problem glad I could help. And if the issue is resolved now then please click the green mark to accept the answer :) And good luck with the rest of your code.

Answer (score 0):

First things first:
You won't need your `text` variable since we will be replacing it with a more appropriate data structure. You need one to store the names that you found so far in the file, along with an integer (number of occurrences) for each name that you found. 
Like [Dmitry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1828937/dmitry-ginzburg) said, the best data structure you can use for this particular case is `Hashtable` or `HashMap`.

Assuming that the file structure is a single name per line without any punctuation or spaces, your code would look something like this:

```
try {
    Hashtable<String,Integer> table = new Hashtable<String,Integer>();
    file = input.readLine();
    read = new BufferedReader (new FileReader(file));
    while ((line = read.readLine()) != null) {
        line.trim();
        if(table.containsKey(line))
            table.put(line, table.get(line)+1);
        else
            table.put(line, 1);                
    }
    System.out.println(table); // looks pretty good and compact on the console... :)
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("File was not found.");          
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("An error has occured.");            
}
```

Comment: Actually, there's not such a thing like `HashTable`, but there is [`Hashtable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) (watch case)

Comment: Actually pasted the code in Eclipse to see if I had any syntax errors but forgot to change it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I want to discuss the logic you used initially to solve the problem of uniqueness of values in an array of strings.

You just compared two cells of the array, and supposing if they are not equal this means that the name of textarray[i] is unique !

This is false, because it can occur later on while your "unique" boolean variable was set to true.

example: 
john | luke| john|charlotte|
comparing the first and second will give you that both john and luke are unequal and comparing them again will say also that they are unequal too when the "i" of loop advances, but this is not the truth.

so lets imagine that we have no map in java, how to solve this with algorithms ?

I will help you with an idea.

1 - create a function that takes in parameter the string that you want to verify and the table
2- then loop all the table testing if the string is equal the cell of the current table if yes, return null or -1
3- if you finish looping the table until the last cell of the array, this means that your string is unique just print if on screen.
4- call this function textarray.length times
and you will have on your screen only the unique names.