# What are the advantages and disadvantages of reading an entire file into a single String as opposed to reading it line by line?

Tags: java, file-io, java.util.scanner

Specifically, my end goal is to store every comma separated word from the file in a `List<String>` and I was wondering which approach I should take.

Approach 1:

```
String fileContents = new Scanner(new File("filepath")).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(fileContents.split("\\s*,\\s*"));
```

Approach 2:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("filepath")).useDelimiter(",");
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
while (s.hasNext()){
    list.add(s.next());
}
s.close();
```

Comment: Approach 3: `Line<String> list = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("filepath"));`

Comment: @JonSkeet, do you mean to say I should adopt 'Approach 3' or that's also a way to do it? Also, you meant to say `List<String> list` right?

Comment: But the OP wants to read all the words not all lines in the list

Comment: @NitinDandriyal - Jon Skeet's code replaces the first line of Approach 1

Comment: @StephenC no it doesn't? You still will have to iterate the result list to split up commas

Comment: @NitinDandriyal - It replaces **the first line** of Approach 1 ... not both lines.

Comment: Why save all the string in a List? One should read from file and process it while reading. Adding things to list just add an extra step unless you want to process that data many times.

Comment: @BruceWayne: I misunderstood the requirement to read words rather than lines. But my approach does have the advantage of closing the file handle even in the face of an exception...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Approach #1 will read the entire file into memory.  This has a couple of performance-related issues:

- If the file is big that uses a lot of memory.
- Because of the way that the character's need to be accumulated by the `Scanner.next()` call, the characters may need to be copied 2 or even 3 times.
- There are other inefficiencies due to the fact that you are using a general pattern matching engine for a very specific purpose.

Approach #3 (which is Approach #1 with the File reading done better) addresses a lot of the efficiency issues, but you still hold the entire file contents in memory.

Approach #2 is best from memory usage perspective because you don't hold the entire file contents as a single string or buffer<sup>1</sup>.  The performance is also *likely* to be best because (my intuition says) this approach avoids at least one copy of the characters.

However, if this really matters, you should benchmark the alternatives, bearing in mind 2 things:

- "Premature optimization" is usually wasted effort.  (Or to put it another, the chances are that the performance of this part of your code really doesn't matter.  The performance bottleneck is likely somewhere else.)
- There a lot of pitfalls for writing Java benchmarks that can lead to bogus performance measures and incorrect conclusions.

---

The other thing to note is that what you are trying to do (create a list of all "words" in order) does not scale.  For a large enough input file, the application will run out of heap space.  If you anticipate running this on input files larger than 100Mb or so, it may start to become a concern.

The solution may be to convert your processing into something that is more "stream" based ... so that you don't need to have a list of all words in memory.

This is essentially the same problem as the problem with Approach #1.

---

<sup>1 - unless the file is small and fits into the buffer ... and then the whole question is largely moot.</sup>

Comment: What if it was in fact a small file? What would change in your answer? Which method has lower time complexity (assuming of course memory is not an issue)?

Comment: Probably approach #2 is still faster.  But if the file is small then the performance probably doesn't matter.

Comment: @StephenC - "*the way that the character's need to be accumulated by the `Scanner.next()` call*" - Could you elaborate on that point?

Comment: @BruceWayne - read the source code for Scanner, Pattern, Matcher, StringBuilder, etcetera.  That is the only way you are going to get a good understanding of what happens behind the scenes here.

Comment: Approach 2 is the best one. Faster and works for any size of the file.

Comment: @Alex - 1) that's what I said (re performance) ... except that I don't present any >>evidence<< that that Approach #2 is fastet.  Do you have some concrete evidence, or are you just agreeing with my opinion?  2) It won't work for any size of file.  If the file is large enough then you either can't hold the list in memory, or you can't represent it at all (as an array list).

Comment: @StephenC what do you by creating a stream "The solution may be to convert your processing into something that is more "stream" based "

Comment: That will depend on the application that is using the huge list of all words.  The OP doesn't describe their application.  There is no universal answer, and depending on the application the approach may not even be feasible.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the entire file into memory when you don't actually need to you are:

- wasting time: nothing is processed until you've read the entire file
- wasting space
- using a technique that won't scale to large files.

Doing this has nothing to recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

Approach 1:

Limit of String's maximum size i.e. a String of max length `Integer.MAX_VALUE` only is possible or the largest possible array at runtime

Hence, Prefer Approach 2 if it is a very large fie